# React: Unificar options dentro de selects combo con distintos valores de un Array

Tags: array, reactjs, map

Obtengo el resultado de la captura usando este mapeado. Los identrificadores son idénticos en dos casos distintos:

```
  const duplicados = [
     {uid: 'd981560bc1604e6c995d2263391aeefc', name: 'How is the Billing?', answer: 'Event Triger' },
     {uid: 'd981560bc1604e6c995d2263391aeefc', name: 'How is the Billing?', answer: 'Per Transaction' },
     {uid: '6a2701c7ed1a4f9c83748095b2815ce7', name: 'Subscription:Which is frequency of the billing?', answer: 'third answer'},
     {uid: '6a2701c7ed1a4f9c83748095b2815ce7', name: 'Subscription:Which is frequency of the billing?', answer: 'fourth answer' },
     {uid: '6a2701c7ed1a4f9c83748095b2815ce7', name: 'Subscription:Which is frequency of the billing?', answer: 'five answer' }
     ]

                 {duplicados &&
                      duplicados.map((questmapn: any, index: any) => (
                        <>
                          {questmapn.name}
                          <select className="form-control">
                              <>
                                <option>{questmapn.answer}</option>
                              </>
                          </select>
                        </>
                  ))}
```

[image: mapeado]

Necesito unificar los select combo mostrando solamente un enunciado y un select con los options dentro, más o menos como en la captura de la derecha, usando los uid idénticos de cada registro.

[image: mapeado2]         [image: captura de la derecha]

Existe alguna manera de hacerlo desde el map? hay que usar una función específica?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado una buena manera de llevar a cabo la separación por identificador usando **reduce** en una función aparte.

```
const duplicados = [
 {uid: 'd981560bc1604e6c995d2263391aeefc', name: 'How is the Billing?', answer: 'Event Triger' },
 {uid: 'd981560bc1604e6c995d2263391aeefc', name: 'How is the Billing?', answer: 'Per Transaction' },
 {uid: '6a2701c7ed1a4f9c83748095b2815ce7', name: 'Subscription:Which is frequency of the billing?', answer: 'third answer'},
 {uid: '6a2701c7ed1a4f9c83748095b2815ce7', name: 'Subscription:Which is frequency of the billing?', answer: 'fourth answer' },
 {uid: '6a2701c7ed1a4f9c83748095b2815ce7', name: 'Subscription:Which is frequency of the billing?', answer: 'five answer' }
 ]


  const splittedData = duplicados.reduce((acc: any, curr: any) => {
   const { uid, name, answer } = curr;
   if (!acc[uid]) {
    acc[uid] = { name, items: [] };
   }
   acc[uid].items.push(answer);
   return acc;
  }, {});

  //6a2701c7ed1a4f9c83748095b2815ce7: {name: 'Subscription:Which is frequency of the billing?', items: Array(3)}
  //d981560bc1604e6c995d2263391aeefc: {name: 'How is the Billing?', items: Array(2)}
```

Para posteriormente renderizarlo usando **Object.keys** en el map de la siguiente manera:

```
      {Object.keys(splittedData).map((key, index) => (
          <>
           {`${splittedData[key].name}`}
              <select className="form-control mb-4">
              {splittedData[key].items.map(
              (item: any, index: any) => (
                 <option>{` ${item}`}</option>
              )
           )}
              </select>
           </>
        ))}
```

El resultado queda tal como necesitaba:

[image: resultado optimo]